# Find 2nd minimum along second axis in a 2-D numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array like this

```
[[ 1, 5, 9, 7],
 [ 5, 8, 9, 7],
 [-9, 6, 2, 3]]
```

I want second minimum from every array present in the 2D array like this

```
[5,7,2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you want the second minimum from each **row** of the
source (*2-D*) array.

To get it, just sort the source array along *axis=1* and then take
the second column (numbering from 0, so the column number is actually *1*):

```
result = np.sort(arr, axis=1)[:,1]
```

The result is:

```
array([5, 7, 2])
```